# Are there spritebatch drawing limitations on monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame, spritebatch

I've reached a point that it seems when I draw too much on screen, monogame starts doing weird things.

When I call this code in the Draw method

```
public void drawDialogBox()
    {
        if (dialogueBoxOn == 1)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, null, Matrix.CreateScale(GameGlobals.zoom));
            spriteBatch.Draw(dialogBoxChara, new Vector2(89, 18), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(dialogBoxTexture, new Vector2(0, 108), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "àéùaDASASCZadhkjashdash", new Vector2(4, 108), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
```

This happens:

[image]

This code is supposed to show the character, the textBox itself and the text. But the text isn't drawn correctly. If I comment one of the draw lines, it works.

[image]

Or this (if I only comment the character line)

[image]

Any ideas of what is happening here? I thought it was some SpriteBatch limitations, but I don't know...

EDIT: After following @Jon advice, i've reached this state

[image]

Now it shows the character and dialog properly, but the background and the walls are not displayed now. I have all the walls like this:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(leftcenterright4, new Vector2(0, 53), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);
```

And the background

```
spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

And the code from earlier fixed:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(dialogBoxChara, new Vector2(89, 18),null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
spriteBatch.Draw(dialogBoxTexture, new Vector2(0, 108),null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0.1f);
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "àéùaDASASCZadhkjashdash", new Vector2(4, 108), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Comment: Somehow I've managed to solve this. With the help of @Jon. What I did, first, set all the layerdepth acordingly, after that, I've tried to change the resolution multiplier of my game to 1, and...It was working. Now it seems I've been causing the problem by trying to make zoom directly and not with RenderTarget2D. I will try to learn how to use that.

Comment: cool looking game btw.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. Also, I've finally get it to work as intended. With Jon's help here and on monogame forums. http://community.monogame.net/t/scaling-zooming-game-window/7824/16 I'll leave the link here, maybe will need it sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an override of the SpriteBatch.Draw() function in order to specify what layer you want to draw your sprites on.  You are already specifying "FrontToBack" sort mode in your initialization so that is good.

Take a look here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx

More specifically, take a look at the "layerDepth" property.  This is what you are looking for.  Set this according to the order you want to draw your sprites on.

```
spriteBatch.Draw (texture, position, null, color, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None. 0.5f);
```

Comment: `spriteBatch.Draw(dialogBoxChara, new Vector2(89, 18),null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);` I've tried this on the character, but the sprite isn't showing now.

Comment: Do this for all your draw calls,making sure you set that float value for the layerdepth accordingly

Comment: I can't get it to work. I've also tried in a new window with only one sprite, and to no avail. `spriteBatch.Draw(mainMenuIndexSpr, new Vector2(89, 18), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, -100000f);` I've tried diferent values for "layerdepth".

Comment: the layerdepth value must be between 0.0f, and 1.0f

Comment: Ah, haha, true. 0 is the farthest or nearest?

Comment: Directly from the link I posted...  "The depth of a layer. By default, 0 represents the front layer and 1 represents a back layer. Use SpriteSortMode if you want sprites to be sorted during drawing."

Comment: Main post updated with the new issues.